# Why do you need to this line of code?

Tags: perl

Here is the code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
my ($items,
@aryitems,
@aryitems2,
$search,
$size,
$num);
@aryitems2=('Chattahoochee','committee','bookkeeper'
,'millennium','cappuccino','Tattle','Illiad','Mississippi',
'Tennessee');
$size=@aryitems2;
print "The size of the array is $size\n";
print "Enter the string to search:";
chomp ($search=<STDIN>);
foreach (@aryitems2)
{
$num=0;
$pos=0;
print "The word is $_\n";
if (/$search/i)
{
    print "The pattern is '$search' and found in the word $_\n";
    while ($pos<(length $_) and $pos!=-1)
    {
        $pos=index ($_,$search,$pos);
        if ($pos!=-1)
        {
        $pos++;
        $num++;
        }
    }
    print "the number of times '$search' is found in this word is $num\n";
    }
    else
    {
    print "the pattern is '$search' and is not found in $_\n";
    }
}
```

The part I don't get is

```
$pos=index ($_,$search,$pos);
```

What is the purpose of this code? How come it's not

```
$pos=index ($_,$pos);
```

or

```
$pos=index($search,$pos);
```

etc...

Why do you need it?

Comment: If you don't need it, delete it. If that breaks something find out why.

Answer (score 2):

You really can't get around specifying both the string you want to find (`$search`), and the string in which to look (`$_`). So, at a minimum, you need

```
$pos = index($_, $search);
```

Why wasn't that used? Because that finds the first match, but the goal is to find all matches. `index` will start looking at the position given by the third parameter if give, allowing the loop to find every instance of `$search` in `$_`.

Note that because `$pos++;` was used instead of `$pos += length($search);`, overlapping matches are possible. For example, if you were search for `abab` in `abababab`, your algorithm would find 3 matches instead of 2.

---

Cleaned up code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my @words = qw( Chattahoochee committee bookkeeper millennium cappuccino Tattle Illiad Mississippi Tennessee );

my ($search) = @ARGV
    or die("usage\n");

for my $word (@words) {
    my $count = 0;
    my $pos = 0;
    while (1) {
        $pos = index($word, $search, $pos);
        last if $pos < 0;

        ++$count;
        ++$pos;
    }

    say "$_ contains $count instances of $search";
}
```

---

Using match operator instead of `index`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings qw( all );
use feature qw( say );

my @words = qw( Chattahoochee committee bookkeeper millennium cappuccino Tattle Illiad Mississippi Tennessee );

my ($search) = @ARGV
    or die("usage\n");

for my $word (@words) {
    my $count = 0;
    ++$count while $word =~ /\Q$search/g;
    say "$_ contains $count instances of $search";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's there so you can count the number of times the pattern is found in the word. It keeps track of where the pattern was previously found so that subsequent searches start further into the word and don't find occurrences of the pattern that have already been discovered.